# R.matlab cannot set MATLAB function

Tags: r, matlab

I was trying to reproduce the `setfunction` example in `R.matlab`. My code is

```r
library(R.matlab)
Matlab$startServer()
matlab <- Matlab()
isOpen <- open(matlab)

setFunction(matlab, " \
  function [win, aver] = dice(B) \
    %Play the dice game B times \
    gains = [-1, 2, -3, 4, -5, 6]; \
    plays = unidrnd(6, B, 1); \
    win = sum(gains(plays)); \
  aver = win/B; \
")
```

I encountered the error:
[image]

I also tried adding an `end` at the end of the MATLAB function, but still had the same error.

How can I avoid the error and set the MATLAB function within R?

Comment: If you copy/pasted the code from here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R.matlab/R.matlab.pdf, try making sure there are no illegal white space characters after the copy/paste.

Comment: @user13267 I tried typing in the code word by word. Still have the error.

Comment: In your code, the function definition starts with a newline character and a space, which is not proper syntax. Make it a oneliner for clarity `setFunction(matlab, "function [win, aver] = dice(B) ... `and then at the end `end")`

Comment: @Kylar I did what you said, but it didn't work out. The error message is the same.

Comment: Please don't post screen shots of error messages. See here for why: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/7328782

Answer (score 1):

Please remove the two white spaces around the equality sign = so that the first line becomes:

```
function [win, aver]=dice(B) \
```

This worked for me.